# Android: how to cancel a request of Location update with intent?

Tags: android

I registered a PendingIntent to requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, PendingIntent). But when my broadcast receiver receives this intend, how do I remove this request with removeUpdates(PendingIntent)? The receiver doesn't hold a reference to the original **PendingIntent**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create an equivalent `PendingIntent`. In other words, create an `Intent` that matches the one you used originally (though you can skip any extras), wrap that in the same sort of `PendingIntent` that you used originally, and use that `PendingIntent` in the `removeUpdates()` call.

Comment: Thank you. In my receiver's onReceive(context, intent) method, I called PendingIntent origPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) right away with the same intent passed in to remove the updates. But somehow, it didn't remove the update request. I can still receive the updates.

Comment: @wei: Try getting rid of `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. It turns out that I have to create a new Intent instance(not sure why, tho)and set the flag to 0 to make it work.