# Location manager doesnt remove location updates!

Tags: android, geolocation, android-intent, locationmanager, android-pendingintent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: how to cancel a request of Location update with intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031630/android-how-to-cancel-a-request-of-location-update-with-intent)

I am trying to disable a pending intent(broadcast) which I have previously created in a different activity but I can't get it to work. I've read that I should recreate the intent(with the same extras and everything), pass it as a parameter so that I can instantiate the pendingIntent and then pass the pendingIntent as a parameter to the location managers removeUpdates method.

In other words:

---

```
Bundle extra = new Bundle();

extra.putString("name", extras.getString("poiName")); //create same extras

extra.putInt("id", extras.getInt("rowId")); //create same extras

Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);  

intent.putExtra(PROX_ALERT_INTENT, extra);  //put same extras in the intent

PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(),extras.getInt("rowId") , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  //pass in the intent

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                                               locationManager.removeUpdates(proximityIntent);  //remove pendingIntent
```

---

That didn't work so I thought that it might have to do with the intent that im passing in being a new object and not the same with the one used in order to create the pending intent.

So I tried removing the pendingIntent right after I create it but that didnt work either:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    extras.putString("name", poiName);

    extras.putInt("id", requestCode);

    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

    intent.putExtra(PROX_ALERT_INTENT, extras);

    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), requestCode , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    locationManager.addProximityAlert(
        latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
        longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
        POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
        PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration 
        proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
   );
    locationManager.removeUpdates(proximityIntent);
```

---

Can you please help me with that??? Its been bugging be since wednesday...wish i had more reputation to put a boundy on this one...

Thanks

mike

Comment: Mike, if you create a PendingIntent and then requestLocationUpdates() upon it, you must removeUpdates() on that *same* PendingIntent object.  You cannot use a *new* PendingIntent() or Intent .. you'll have to get the original PendingIntent to the second activity somehow.

Comment: @DJC I managed to get that working by recreating and cancelling the pending intent...apparently it doesnt matter if its not the actual object as long as you pass in an intent with the exact same extras and you can get hold of the pending intent that you previously created...kinda weird but it works...thanks for the reply anyway...

Comment: @DJC Well now that i think about it...you are basically overwriting the previous pendingIntent object so it ceases to exist and the new one takes its place...so you have an actual reference to the pending intent and you can then cancel it :)

Comment: There's a very clear answer by CommonsWare here: [Android: how to cancel a request of Location update with intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032556/383414)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it by recreating the intent and then calling .cancel() on the pending intent...